# Number Theory Exponentiation

Tags: number-theory

Find all x in Z such that $x^{x^x} = 2 (mod 19)$. I don't see a way to do this. I know that you can work through it with a compute easily, but there should be a human proof. I tried working with primitive roots, but that didn't get anywhere.

I think it is a little bit of a stretch to say that this can be done easily via trial and error by hand. A computer could do it quickly using exponentiation by squaring, but there has to be a nicer way.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) we know that unless $x \equiv 0 \pmod {19}, x^{18} \equiv 1 \pmod {19}$, so you can reduce the upper $x^x \pmod {18}$

Answer (score 0):

Well, the key is that $x^p = x \mod p.$ (Fermat's little theorem). This means that you only need to compute $x^x$ mod 18 for ever $x$ between $0$ and $18.$ and then raise the same $x$ to the resulting quantity mod $19.$ It can be easily done by hand.

Comment: But $1^1$ and $20^{20}$ are different modulo 18 (one is even, one odd)